# File uploads for non-administrators fail

Tags: 7, files

I've got a file field on a profile type. The allowed file extensions is .pdf. When I try to upload a pdf file with the admin account it works very well, but when I try to upload with another authenticated user, the message "An illegal choice has been detected. Please contact the site administrator" appears.

Comment: Check the log, there could be a more helpful error message there.

Comment: Also, report any modules you have enabled that may handle file access or node access restrictions. Likely, your site lacks the permission necessary for that role to upload the file types.